# Getting to grips with raster data?

Tags: raster, references

I always have trouble understanding the different characteristics of raster data formats - Bands, RGB, Alpha, Color tables, Classification, Stretching, single color setting etc.

Can anyone offer me any texts, manuscripts, tutorials, notes or books which would explain to me in a "not too" technical way how these formats work?

Comment: Paper version of ERDAS Field Guide is very good. Now it seems to be wikified https://wiki.hexagongeospatial.com/index.php?title=Main_page but older PDF versions seem to be available for downloading and for free.

Comment: ArcGIS' [help files on raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_raster_data/009t00000002000000/) are another good resource.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question is in the category of "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." (see [help/dont-ask]).  As a result I am going to put it On Hold as being too broad.  To get it re-opened please edit it so that it perhaps focuses on a specific place where you are stuck when trying to work with raster data showing your research into that specific topic so far.

Answer (score 1):

Paper version of ERDAS Field Guide is very good. Nowadays it is wikified

http://wiki.hexagongeospatial.com/index.php?title=Main_page

Older PDF versions seem to be also available for downloading and for free.

Answer (score 1):

Rasters are made of pixels, and pixels can only store one value. If you need to store more than one value with rasters, you need more than one pixel at each location. For storing different types of information in a single raster, you use several **bands**. The rasters are called with different names depending on the softwares : multi-band, raster stack, vector image, composite(but composite has another meaning, so it should be avoided).

Most of the terms that you mention are related to the display of raster data. You should then distinguish one band rasters and multi-band raster

with multi-band rasters you can display up to 3(or 4) information at the same time. Human eyes have receptors for three colors (red/green/blue = **RGB**) so you can select 3 of your bands and assign them to one of the three fundamental colors. This is the so-called "color composite". In some cases, a fourth band can be used to adjust the transparency: the **alpha** band. For remote sensing images, we will talk about RGB composite when the red/blue/green that you visualize correspond with the red/blue/green bands of the sensors. Otherwise it is a false color composite, which is often describe with the band numbers (e.g. 4-3-2).

With one band raster, you can assign one color for each value using a look up table (the **color table**, for example 1->red, 2->green...), or interpolate a continuous color ramp based on the pixel values.

For any type of continuous raster, **streching** is used to enhance your contrast (hence your ability to visually distinguish two values). Your monitor assign an intensity value to each pixel, and you want to use the full range of values of your monitor. So you need an on-the-fly transformation of the pixel values into monitor values.